# Why use onGenerateRoute() vs ModalRoute.of() in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

Is there any reason to use one over the other in any given circumstance? I'm trying to figure out why there are two ways of doing this. I'm referring to the "navigate with arguments" cookbook recipe:

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`ModalRoute.of` is used to build the route *after* it has been pushed in the navigation history.

`onGenerateRoute` does the same, but *before* that route is pushed in the navigation history.

`ModalRoute.of` is enough for most use-cases. But `onGenerateRoute` is more flexible. It allows building the route conditionally based on what the argument is, or type checking that the argument is valid:

```dart
onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
  if (settings.name == '/custom-route') {
    assert(settings.arguments is MyCustomArgument);
  }
}
```

or:

```dart
onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
  if (settings.name == '/users') {
    if (settings.arguments != null) {
      return UserDetailsRoute(id: settings.arguments);
    }
    else {
      return UserListRoute();
    }
  }
}
```